# Executing two commands in one line

Tags: unix, command-line, command

I have a particular problem that requires me to run `cd` command with `rm` following afterwards. But I'm restrained by the fact that I have to execute both commands in a single line.

Let's say I have two folders in my current directory, "A" and "B". And within "A" folder, I have two more folders, "Fol1" and "Fol2", with a text file called "File1". And lastly, within "Fol1" and "Fol2", they both have a single text file (doesn't matter what they're called).

To give an illustration:

```
(Current dir)                
                             A                            B
                             |                            |
                ---------------------------
                |            |            |
                Fol1        Fol2       File1
                |            |
                FileA       FileB
```

I want to go into "A", then remove everything remove everything except what's in "Fol1" and "Fol2".

I've found that to remove everything except certain directories you can run:

```
rm -r !(Fol1|Fol2)
```

And I saw on another post that you can use `&` to combine two commands together. So from the current directory, I decided to run:

```
cd A & rm -r !(Fol1|Fol2)
```

But when I ran those commands, I got:

```
[1] 17854
[1]+  Done                    cd A
```

And it ended up deleting "A" and "B" and everything else in it.

Is there something that I'm missing within the commands? Anything would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand just ran the `cd` command in the background, which started a subshell, changed directories, the exited. Then the `rm -r` ran in the current directory, which had no Fol1 or Fol2 to ignore.  You want a semi-colon to separate commands like this:

```
cd A; rm -r !(Fol1|Fol2)
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not amazing.  Just been there, done that years before you :-) "Experience is what you get, right after you need it".